# Hold messages in JMS queue

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jms-topic

I have an attribute within message to be processed by a consumer. For some reason if the message cannot be processed, I want this message and all other messages in the queue with same attribute value to be put on hold for a configurable time period. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look at "Delivery Delay" in JMS 2.0 where in a message will not be made available for specified amount of time after it is put to a queue. Here is the link for more details  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119200_.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any JMS implementation which offers the functionality your looking for. This kind of behavior isn't described in the JMS specification. In general, JMS messages are treated as independent units where the consumption of (or the failure to consume) one message has no impact on any of the other messages.